# Detox Test device.disableSynchronization() works on iOS but not android

Tags: android, react-native, e2e-testing, detox

My test suite runs fine on iOS, the app has many background processes running that prevent large portions of the tests from working in synchronized mode. The desynced commands run properly on the iOS simulator, but when I run them on the android emulator it is as if I never called await device.disableSynchronization().

The tests still hang and the console logs:

```
The app is busy, due to:
     - Enqueued timers
     - Animations running on screen
```

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Further review shows the error message:

> The app has not responded to the network requests below:

The odd thing is the listed network request *has* been completed. The request upon which the app purportedly has not responded is a button push that navigates to a new screen which incurs a somewhat lengthy network request. After the network request completes other processes continually run necessitating the disabled synchronization. Since Detox is still waiting on some response from the app about the button tap, it does not move on to the next, desynchronized, actions. Is there any way to ensure that Detox receives the response of this .tap()?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A deeper investigation reveals that this is likely caused by a lingering animation that, for whatever reason device.disablesynchronization() ignores on Android builds. I am now working on mocking this file based on the out-of-date documentation provided by wix.